# How to implement a stack containing function call for a PIC in C

Tags: c, stack, interrupt, pic

I'm currently programming a PIC in C with MPLAB X (+ compiler XC8)

In my code, I have some interruptions (inter1, inter2, ..) which are each composed of urgent and non-urgent operations (urg1, urg2, .., n_urg1, n_urg2, ..).

So I'd like a code with the following structure :

```
stack s; // FIFO or other
main() {
   while (true) {
      if (!isEmpty(s)) {
         doNextFunction(s);
      }
   }
 }

void interrupt inter1() {
   urg1(); // urgent code
   addStack(n_urg1);
}

void n_urg1() {
   // non-urgent code
}
```

How can I implement that kind of stack ? Is there something in the standard library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correct, then that compiler is rather primitive, I don't think you can use the std library.

If you need to implement it all by yourself, you can use an array of function pointers:

```
#include <string.h> // for memmove()

#define STACK_MAX   10

typedef enum
{
    Int,
    Boolean
} VariantType;

typedef struct
{
    VariantType type;
    union {
        int intValue;
        bool booleanValue;
    } value;
} Variant;

typedef bool (*FunctionPtr)(Variant data);

typedef struct
{
    FunctionPtr ptr;
    Variant var;
} FunctionCall;

FunctionCall functionStack[STACK_MAX];
int functionStackUse = 0;

bool addStack(FunctionPtr ptr, Variant var)
{
    if (functionStackUse >= STACK_MAX)
        return false; // stack full
    functionStack[functionStackUse].ptr = ptr;
    functionStack[functionStackUse].var = var;
    functionStackUse++;
    return true;
}

bool callNextFunction(void)
{
    // TODO: disable inter1
    if (functionStackUse > 0)
    {
        // get first function on stack
        FunctionCall functionCall = functionStack[0];
        functionStackUse--;
        // remove first function from stack
        memmove((void*)functionStack, (void*)(functionStack + 1), functionStackUse * sizeof(functionStack[0]));
        // TODO: re-enable inter1
        // call function with arguments
        return (*functionCall.ptr)(functionCall.var);
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: re-enable inter1
        return false; // no more functions
    }
}

void main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        callNextFunction();
        // TODO add some delay otherwise you're constantly disabling inter1 (in doNextFunction)
    }
}


bool n_urg1(Variant var)
{
    if (var.type == Int)
    {
        int i = var.value.intValue;
        // do something
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void inter1(void)
{
    Variant var;
    var.type = Int;
    var.value.intValue = 45;
    addStack(n_urg1, var);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! But, why does I have to disable interrupts when calling doNextFunction ?
In my real code, I have a lot of 'inter' and 'n_urg' functions. And the aim is that 'n_urg' functions can be interrupt by all the 'inter' functions.
I think that a mutex (like the answer below) can fix the access to the stack problem, isn't it ?

Comment: And what if some of the 'n_urg' functions needs arguments ?

Comment: The you first take the function pointer from stack and call n_urg after re-enabling the interrupts, I will update my answer. All of your method will have to receive the same argument(s), otherwise you can't create an array.

Comment: I've added a variant approach so you can pass a function argument.